# Posts not updated when created via Netlify CMS

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

I've created a new post through Netlify CMS however the posts are not updating on the Gatsby site. I thoroughly followed the [add Netlify CMS to existing sites](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/add-to-your-site/) documentation and everything seems to be working fine except the posts is not showing up on my site.

Here are the links to my site with repo and the `config.yml` file:

My site: https://my-blogger.netlify.app/

My repo: https://github.com/mohammedasker/blogger

**config.yml**

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: master

media_folder: "static/media"
public_folder: "/media"

collections:
  - name: "blog"
    label: "Blog"
    folder: "src/content"
    create: true
    slug: "{{year}}-{{month}}-{{day}}-{{slug}}"
    fields:
      - { label: "Layout", name: "layout", widget: "hidden", default: "blog" }
      - { label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string" }
      - { label: "Slug", name: "slug", widget: "string" }
      - { label: "Draft", name: "draft", widget: "boolean", default: true }
      - { label: "Description", name: "description", widget: "text" }
      - { label: "Publish Date", name: "date", widget: "datetime" }
      - { label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown" }
```

**Additional information**
I've noticed in the deploy details that the `path` value is `null` in "gatsby-node.js" and this might prevent the post from being updated. That being said, the problem continues to persist when the deploy was all green.

**Build log:**

```
8:26:23 PM: Build ready to start
8:26:25 PM: build-image version: ca811f47d4c1cbd1812d1eb6ecb0c977e86d1a1d
8:26:25 PM: build-image tag: v3.3.20
8:26:25 PM: buildbot version: be8ecf2af866e16fa4301cc5c14de2ccbbb21cf4
8:26:25 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
8:26:25 PM: Starting to download cache of 139.0MB
8:26:26 PM: Finished downloading cache in 725.651881ms
8:26:26 PM: Starting to extract cache
8:26:32 PM: Finished extracting cache in 6.022644176s
8:26:32 PM: Finished fetching cache in 6.792240623s
8:26:32 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
8:26:32 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
8:26:33 PM: Different publish path detected, going to use the one specified in the Netlify configuration file: 'public' versus 'public/' in the Netlify UI
8:26:33 PM: Starting build script
8:26:34 PM: Installing dependencies
8:26:34 PM: Python version set to 2.7
8:26:34 PM: Started restoring cached node version
8:26:36 PM: Finished restoring cached node version
8:26:37 PM: v12.18.0 is already installed.
8:26:38 PM: Now using node v12.18.0 (npm v6.14.4)
8:26:38 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
8:26:38 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
8:26:38 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.1, read from environment
8:26:39 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.1
8:26:39 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
8:26:39 PM: 5.2 is already installed.
8:26:39 PM: Using Swift version 5.2
8:26:39 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
8:26:39 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
8:26:39 PM: Started restoring cached yarn cache
8:26:39 PM: Finished restoring cached yarn cache
8:26:40 PM: Installing NPM modules using Yarn version 1.22.4
8:26:40 PM: yarn install v1.22.4
8:26:40 PM: [1/4] Resolving packages...
8:26:41 PM: success Already up-to-date.
8:26:41 PM: Done in 0.84s.
8:26:41 PM: NPM modules installed using Yarn
8:26:41 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
8:26:41 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
8:26:41 PM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
8:26:41 PM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
8:26:41 PM: Installing missing commands
8:26:41 PM: Verify run directory
8:26:42 PM: ​
8:26:42 PM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
8:26:42 PM: │        Netlify Build        │
8:26:42 PM: └─────────────────────────────┘
8:26:42 PM: ​
8:26:42 PM: ❯ Version
8:26:42 PM:   @netlify/build 3.0.1
8:26:42 PM: ​
8:26:42 PM: ❯ Flags
8:26:42 PM:   deployId: 5f25a5bfbf80940007d20ec6
8:26:42 PM:   mode: buildbot
8:26:42 PM: ​
8:26:42 PM: ❯ Current directory
8:26:42 PM:   /opt/build/repo
8:26:42 PM: ​
8:26:42 PM: ❯ Config file
8:26:42 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
8:26:42 PM: ​
8:26:42 PM: ❯ Context
8:26:42 PM:   production
8:26:42 PM: ​
8:26:42 PM: ┌───────────────────────────────────┐
8:26:42 PM: │ 1. Build command from Netlify app │
8:26:42 PM: └───────────────────────────────────┘
8:26:42 PM: ​
8:26:42 PM: $ gatsby build
8:26:45 PM: success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.025s
8:26:46 PM: success load plugins - 0.796s
8:26:46 PM: success onPreInit - 0.009s
8:26:46 PM: success delete html and css files from previous builds - 0.012s
8:26:46 PM: success initialize cache - 0.006s
8:26:46 PM: success copy gatsby files - 0.032s
8:26:46 PM: success onPreBootstrap - 0.007s
8:26:46 PM: success createSchemaCustomization - 0.058s
8:26:46 PM: success Checking for changed pages - 0.000s
8:26:46 PM: success source and transform nodes - 0.145s
8:26:46 PM: success building schema - 0.359s
8:26:46 PM: error Your site's "gatsby-node.js" must set the page path when creating a page.
8:26:46 PM: The page object passed to createPage:
8:26:46 PM: {
8:26:46 PM:     "path": null,
8:26:46 PM:     "component": "/opt/build/repo/src/templates/blog-post.js",
8:26:46 PM:     "slug": "/2020-07-30-you-should-join-the-100daysofcode-challenge/",
8:26:46 PM:     "context": {}
8:26:46 PM: }
8:26:46 PM: See the documentation for the "createPage" action — https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/actions/#createPage
8:26:46 PM: not finished createPages - 0.020s
8:26:47 PM: ​
8:26:47 PM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
8:26:47 PM: │   "build.command" failed    │
8:26:47 PM: └─────────────────────────────┘
8:26:47 PM: ​
8:26:47 PM:   Error message
8:26:47 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: gatsby build
8:26:47 PM: ​
8:26:47 PM:   Error location
8:26:47 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
8:26:47 PM:   gatsby build
8:26:47 PM: ​
8:26:47 PM:   Resolved config
8:26:47 PM:   build:
8:26:47 PM:     command: gatsby build
8:26:47 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
8:26:47 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/public
8:26:47 PM: Caching artifacts
8:26:47 PM: Started saving node modules
8:26:47 PM: Finished saving node modules
8:26:47 PM: Started saving build plugins
8:26:47 PM: Finished saving build plugins
8:26:47 PM: Started saving yarn cache
8:26:47 PM: Finished saving yarn cache
8:26:47 PM: Started saving pip cache
8:26:47 PM: Finished saving pip cache
8:26:47 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
8:26:47 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
8:26:47 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
8:26:47 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
8:26:47 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
8:26:47 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
8:26:47 PM: Started saving go dependencies
8:26:47 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
8:26:47 PM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
8:26:47 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
8:26:47 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
8:26:47 PM: Finished processing build request in 22.237427248s
```

**Updated: Added "gatsby-node.js" file**

```js
const path = require(`path`)
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `pages` })
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: slug,
    })
  }
}

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const blogPostTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/blog-post.js`)
  return graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            frontmatter {
              path
              draft
              date
            }
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
      return Promise.reject(result.errors)
    }
    result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges
      .filter(({ node }) => !node.frontmatter.draft)
      .forEach(({ node }) => {
        createPage({
          path: node.frontmatter.path,
          component: blogPostTemplate,
          slug: node.fields.slug,
          context: {},
        })
      })
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the `gatsby-node.js` query where you retrieve the `slug` and create pages?

Comment: I'd like to provide the `gatsby-node.js` query, but I'm not sure how I can do that.

Comment: Just edit your question and copy and paste your `gatsby-node.js` code, at least the query and the `createPage` API.

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-build to update contents, since Gatsby is a static site generator.
After only build, you could check updates because Gatsby fetch updated datas from Netlify CMS when you build.

[image]

But you can implement real-time update with Netlify CMS, you need to add markdown pages.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/sourcing-from-netlify-cms